# Get the alpha value of a pixel of a texture in SparkAR

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

I want to see if the alpha value of a given pixel of a given texture is 0.
I tried to get the color via the `Texture Sampler` patch. Then unpack it and read out the last value. If I do it like that the values never change and I get the *"Patch received input of type `ShaderGeneric`, when the type expected was Scalar." error*.

Does anybody know how to get the alpha value of a pixel of a texture in `SparkAR`?
Picture of the patch setup with error shown:

[image]

Comment: Short story : you cannot use shader signal in any logic. It is in the different scope. If you could say what. do you want to achieve, then maybe I could help.

Comment: I move a texture around and wanted to check, if the player is "in" (on a transparent pixel) or "out" (on a non transparent pixel). I solved it for now, by creating a 512x512 long string containig 0 for transparent pixels and 1 for non transparent pixel and checking against that. Works, but I don't thing thats the best way to do that.

Comment: Maybe for your scenario will be better to use BoundingBox? Is it 2d game?

Comment: It is a 2d racing game. So the texture is of a track. BoundingBox couldn't fit the complexity, as I understand it.

Comment: If you don't need physics, simple bounxgBox does a great job. Also you could take a look at circles, the are super cheap to calculate.
Of course if you have only several checks for collision, your approach could be acceptable.